# Temp. variable or method calls? And literal or equivalent variable?

Tags: java

```
 private static final Group[] toGroups (String string)
    {
        int     partialGroupSize = string.length() % GROUP_SIZE;
        boolean hasPartialGroup  = partialGroupSize != 0;
        int     nGroupOffset     = hasPartialGroup ? 1 : 0;
        int     nGroup           = string.length() / GROUP_SIZE + nGroupOffset;
        Group[] groups           = new Group[nGroup];
        for (int i = 0; i < nGroup; i++) {
            boolean isFirstGroup = i == 0;
            int beginIndex = isFirstGroup ? i :
                             GROUP_SIZE * (i - nGroupOffset) + partialGroupSize;
            int   endIndex = isFirstGroup && hasPartialGroup ?
                             beginIndex + partialGroupSize :
                             beginIndex + GROUP_SIZE;
            groups[i] = new Group(Integer.parseInt(string.substring(beginIndex,
                                                                      endIndex)));
        }
        return groups;
    }
```

My first question is one that I found different discussions about, but I still don't know what I should do.
The method `toGroups` is only called once in the program, therefore `.length()` is only called twice on `string` of `toGroups` in the program. So with regards to performance and readability, should I replace `string.length()` with `length` where `int length = string.length();`?
Id est:

```
int     length           = string.length();
int     partialGroupSize = length % GROUP_SIZE;
boolean hasPartialGroup  = partialGroupSize != 0;
int     nGroupOffset     = hasPartialGroup ? 1 : 0;
int     nGroup           = length / GROUP_SIZE + nGroupOffset;
```

My second question is: within the `for` loop, given that when the predicate of the `beginIndex` conditional assignment, `isFirstGroup`, is `true`, `i` must be `0`; should I replace the consequent of the `beginIndex` conditional with a literal `0`?
Id est:

```
int beginIndex = isFirstGroup ? 0 :
                 GROUP_SIZE * (i - nGroupOffset) + partialGroupSize;
```

I reason that because the consequent of `beginIndex` is always `0`, using the equivalent `i` iterator creates an ambiguity in the constancy/variableness of the consequent.

Comment: Also, why did Stack Overflow trim my question? I said, ``Hello everyone!'' at the beginning and it got rid of it.

Comment: you don't have to say hello, just ask the question :)

Comment: it keeps everything on target and to the point - how stack overflow is meant to work

Comment: This might be better on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So with regards to performance and readability ...

Readability is a more important attribute of a well written program than performance.  Indeed, readability is second only to correctness (IMO).

Performance is generally speaking a minor issue.  And in the cases where it is important, large-scale algorithmic efficiency is more critical than "micro" issues such as whether you call a fast method such as `String.length()` once or twice.

(Indeed, there is a good chance that the JIT compiler can figure out that it can safely "hoist" the `String.length()` call out of the loop.  And even if it can't, the next generation of JIT compiler may be able to do this optimization.)

In general, it is best to leave micro-optimizations like this to the JIT compiler, and  focus your effort on more important things.  Only micro-optimize if you have clear evidence (e.g. from profiling) of a significant bottleneck in your code.

> Also, is there anything I should do that I didn't do or is there anything I did that I shouldn't do, stylistically or otherwise?

Yes.

Don't line all your declaration / assignment statements up like that:

- It is a waste of time.
- It doesn't make your code any more readable.  (And if I'm reading your code, I don't care about its artistic qualities ...)
- It violates all mainstream coding standards.

Comment: Do you suppose he's been tarred with the Microsoft brush?

Answer (score 0):

- Stylistically speaking, it may help to use mainstream terminology when you're discussing code (especially here), just to make things easier to understand. You don't typically hear folks talking about the "consequent" or "predicate" unless you're talking about logic programing; more often you'll hear "parameter" or "argument".
- I would use parentheses a bit more -- you can get yourself into some nasty situations with operator precedence trying to chain logical statements. By the way, ternaries are nice, but they are often really painful to read.
- If you're just starting out, make comments your best friend. Later on, you'll want to avoid overcommenting, but overcommenting is better than no comments at all. You have none here and it's hard to suss out what exactly you're trying to accomplish. I'd stick comments near your ternaries to explain why you're doing what you're doing. It likely doesn't matter for this particular bit of code, but in a production environment, someone who has to maintain your code will want to wring your neck if you've left convoluted code with nary a comment in sight.
- In terms of your actual code ... assigning length to a variable isn't going to affect your performance in any dramatic way, especially since this is early on for you. Focus more on getting the logic and syntax down rather than with nitpicks about performance; you can worry about that as you go.

Good luck!